# How to add double quotes in specific location in string array?

Tags: c

I have one certificate where I want to add the double quotes(") at specific location in string array for make it in specific format. I wrote the code but its not working.

Can you tell where I m doing wrong?

certificate which i have

```
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
    MIIGCTCCA/GgAwIBAgIUB2IexWz8meqWx0ihY6f623xszc0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n
    BQAwgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRcw\n
    FQYDVQQKDA5GaXJld2lyZXMgU2FhczEMMAoGA1UECwwDSW9UMRcwFQYDVQQDDA5G\n
    aXJld2lyZXMgU2FhUzEhMB8GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYSYWRtaW5AZmlyZXdpcmVzLmlu\n
    MB4XDTIxMDkwMTE4NDkwMVoXDTMxMDgzMDE4NDkwMVowgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklO\n
    MQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5GaXJld2lyZXMg\n
    5ha68cLo0M9P9qcE9A7BJ1N8CPobH6NoiSMP0Qbj5pPq0udcKyuhzMEu8j3+2Mxw\n
    K2urzHK9941VeRUgWrHqBn+0lBvzQ+3w68Io1cthqly2yuDDHAfG6aQc4DdkvNl5\n
    zdvkpKs09F84c45HBIuDnVeL9jWNfpP9Z8bPKOSdvKxiI8TaNSXbRD6x0jCoewwc\n
    2r9E1hvjg9KV3UGmIQ==\n
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----*/


char *Format(char *unformatterPem)
{
    int unformattedPemLen = strlen(unformatterPem);
    char key[unformattedPemLen + 1];
    strcpy(key, unformatterPem);
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "Length %d Unformat Key %s",unformattedPemLen, key);
    int newUnformattedLen = unformatterPem + 500;
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "Length %d Unformat Key %s",unformattedPemLen, key);
    char newKey[newUnformattedLen];

    int keyI = 0, keyJ = 0, lastInd = 0;
    
    newKey[keyJ] = '"';
    keyJ++;
    //ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: NewKey[0] %s", __LINE__, newKey[keyJ]);
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: NewKey %s", __LINE__, newKey);

    int i = 0;
    for (keyI = 0; keyI < unformattedPemLen;)
    {
        if (strcmp(key[keyI],"\n")==0)
        {
            ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "found at index %d  at %d times. ", keyI, i);
            newKey[keyJ] = key[keyI]; 
            keyI++;
            keyJ++;
            newKey[keyJ] = '"';
        }
        else
        {
            // strcpy(newKey[keyJ], key[keyI]);
            newKey[keyJ] = key[keyI];
            keyI++;
            keyJ++;
        }
    }
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: NewKey %s", __LINE__, newKey);
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: keyI %d", __LINE__, keyI);
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: keyJ %d", __LINE__, keyJ);
    newKey[keyJ] = '"';
    ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "%d: newKey %s", __LINE__, newKey);
    char *returnKey = newKey;
    return returnKey;
}
```

for somewhere in program,

```
char *pkey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGCTCCA/GgAwIBAgIUB2IexWz8meqWx0ihY6f623xszc0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\nBQAwgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTARtaW5AZmlyZXdpcmVzLmlu\nMiBlkN7eNDHQnjHcyuyTS2SVGddsuEEqQe3BA3SgOUvwtOT3DNXDkfM8yV2RgZxZh\nTFSaoxLw4Y1N2lGoAeHeKpdk1IuyqTz+3OM4AWLp6geDypp/Ymt\n2r9E1hvjg9KV3UGmIQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

onst char *newKey = pemFormat(pkey)
```

I want cerificate in

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"                                     
"MIIEBTCCAu2gAwIBAgIUO3Mmd80is3vTSU+IslC+1bMhNdQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n"
"BQAwgZExCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRIw\n"
"EAYDVQQKDAlGaXJld2lyZXMxFTATBgNVBAsMDCBSJkQgUk9PVCBDQTEZMBcGA1UE\n"
"AwwQaW90LmZpcmV3aXJlcy5pbjEhMB8GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYSYWRtaW5AZmlyZXdp\n"
"Oy8z/ASkFrrsHBjcyxCaI5IlKHpv0u3KR3ZS6RwhV2rp850LaHTn0GtHKSihz0Ki\n"
"TEzX0Kb6qtJPPcL9xVcVRmNXX/3KUTZFZQ==\n"                            
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

Edited: Added logs
Logs:

```
I (62880) mqtt.c: Unformat Key -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGCTCCA/GgAwIBAgIUB2IexWz8meqWx0ihY6f623xszc0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRcw
3SoKicL4ea2frAeuIp9gkGVYZYkRkCsD0ePkyYL8TuqSeDgigkogooJVXN1N0Ymt
2r9E1hvjg9KV3UGmIQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Unhandled kernel exception)
Core 0 register dump:
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Unknown reason)
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestion.

Comment: If "its not working" then the reason is "has a bug". If you provide more detailed misbehaviour description you might get more detailed reason descriptions. Please read [ask]. Provide descriptions and examples of what you get in contrast to what you wantand and any other helpful information, like error messages, unwanted behaviour (beyond wrong output).

Comment: What is `ESP_LOGI`? Debug message output?

Comment: Count the lines. For each lines you need to add two more characters. Now you can calculate the size of the destination memory. Copy line by line, adding the opening quote first, and the closing quote right before the newline. Return the new string.

Comment: By the way, you have *undefined behavior* as you return a pointer to the first element in the ***local*** array`newKey`. The life-time of `newKey` ends when the function returns, making the returned pointer invalid. You need to allocate the new string dynamically from the heap.

Comment: `strcmp(key[keyI],"\n")` -> `strcmp(&key[keyI],"\n")`, `strcmp()` take `char*` as parameter, not `char`

Comment: @tstanisl Or possibly `key[keyI] == '\n'` instead of `strcmp`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, definitely, however I just wanted to keep difference minimal

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude its `key[keyI] == '\n'` not working  giving the compiler error so i changed it to `strcmp`

Comment: @tstanisl with `strcmp` no newline will be found unless it is at the end of the string.

Comment: What compiler error? You don't mention any.

Comment: @RaghavJha That sounds unlikely, unless you do something very wrong. `if (key[keyI] == '\n') { ... }` should work perfectly fine. It's your current usage of `strcmp' which is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code quickly revealed by enabling warning in your compiler:

```
so99.c: In function ‘Format’:
so99.c:12:29: warning: initialization of ‘int’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   12 |     int newUnformattedLen = unformatterPem + 500;
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
so99.c:26:23: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   26 |         if (strcmp(key[keyI],"\n")==0)
      |                    ~~~^~~~~~
      |                       |
      |                       char
In file included from so99.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:137:32: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  137 | extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

---

First fix:
Replace:

```
int newUnformattedLen = unformatterPem + 500;
```

with

```
int newUnformattedLen = unformattedPemLen + 500;
```

---

The second issue. Replace

```
strcmp(key[keyI],"\n")==0
```

with

```
strcmp(&key[keyI],"\n")==0
```

However, I guess that the intention was

```
key[keyI] == '\n'
```

because using `strcmp` will succeed *only* if the whole remainnig string was a new line.

---

Next one is returning a local variable what trigger *UB*.

```
    char *returnKey = newKey;
    return returnKey;
```

Note that `newKey` is a automatic VLA, it will released after returning from the `Format` function.

You could use dynamic storage. Replace

```
char newKey[newUnformattedLen];
```

with

```
char *newKey = malloc(newUnformattedLen);
```

---

There is no terminator at the end of `newKey`:

```
newKey[keyJ] = '"';
newKey[keyJ + 1] = 0;
```

---

Next one.
After adding `"` to `newKey` you don't shift `keyJ`. Thus `"` will be **overwritten** in the next iteration.

```
 {
            ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "found at index %d  at %d times. ", keyI, i);
            newKey[keyJ] = key[keyI]; 
            keyI++;
            keyJ++;
            newKey[keyJ] = '"';
            keyJ++;   // fix
        }
```

---

Generally this inner loop should be rewritten as:

```
    for (keyI = 0; keyI < unformattedPemLen;keyI++) {
        if (key[keyI] == '\n') {
            ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "found at index %d  at %d times. ", keyI, i);
            newKey[keyJ++] = '\\';
            newKey[keyJ++] = 'n';
            newKey[keyJ++] = '"';
            newKey[keyJ++] = '\n';
            newKey[keyJ++] = '"';
        } else {
            newKey[keyJ++] = key[keyI];
        }
    }
```

Now it produces the expected output:

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIGCTCCA/GgAwIBAgIUB2IexWz8meqWx0ihY6f623xszc0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\n"
"BQAwgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRcw\n"
"FQYDVQQKDA5GaXJld2lyZXMgU2FhczEMMAoGA1UECwwDSW9UMRcwFQYDVQQDDA5G\n"
"aXJld2lyZXMgU2FhUzEhMB8GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYSYWRtaW5AZmlyZXdpcmVzLmlu\n"
"MB4XDTIxMDkwMTE4NDkwMVoXDTMxMDgzMDE4NDkwMVowgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklO\n"
"MQswCQYDVQQIDAJUUzEMMAoGA1UEBwwDSFlEMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5GaXJld2lyZXMg\n"
"5ha68cLo0M9P9qcE9A7BJ1N8CPobH6NoiSMP0Qbj5pPq0udcKyuhzMEu8j3+2Mxw\n"
"K2urzHK9941VeRUgWrHqBn+0lBvzQ+3w68Io1cthqly2yuDDHAfG6aQc4DdkvNl5\n"
"zdvkpKs09F84c45HBIuDnVeL9jWNfpP9Z8bPKOSdvKxiI8TaNSXbRD6x0jCoewwc\n"
"2r9E1hvjg9KV3UGmIQ==\n"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

---

Other issues:

```
    char key[unformattedPemLen + 1];
    strcpy(key, unformatterPem);
```

it pointless because neither `unformatterPem` not `key` is modified.
Just do:

```
char *key = unformatterPem;
```

or just rename `unformatterPem` to `key`.

---

```
int newUnformattedLen = unformatterPem + 500;
```

is a dangerous heuristic because strings with a few hundred newlines will overflow this buffer. Better compute the required size in advance.

```
int newUnformattedLen = 0;
for (char *s = unformatterPem; *s; ++s)
  if (*s == '\n') newUnformattedLen += 5; // '\n' -> { '\', '\n', '"', '\n', '"' }
  else            newUnformattedLen += 1;
```

when allocation, add extra 3 bytes for first and last `'"'` and the string terminator, check for malloc failure:

```
char *newKey = malloc(newUnformattedLen + 3);
if (!newKey) {
   ESP_LOGI(MQTT_TAG, "No mem");
   return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant modify the string literal. I personally would use standard functions as performance-wise the function execution time is very low compared to the network/bluetooth messages exchange time.

```
char *makestr(const char *src)
{
    #define replacement "\"\n\""
    #define needle "\n"
    #define atfront "\""
    #define atend "\""

    const size_t nlen = sizeof(needle) - 1;
    const size_t rlen = sizeof(replacement) - 1;
    const ssize_t ldiff = rlen - nlen;
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    char *wrk = (char *)src;
    char *newstr;
    int atendfl = 0;

    if(strcmp(src + len - rlen, atend)) {len += sizeof(atend) -1; atendfl = 1;}
    if(strstr(src, atfront) != src) len += sizeof(atfront) - 1;

    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {

        wrk += nlen;
        len += ldiff;
    }
    newstr = malloc(len + 1);
    if(newstr)
    {
        const char *cpos = src;
        const char *ppos = src;
        wrk = newstr;
        if(strstr(src, atfront) != src)
        {
            strcpy(wrk, atfront);
            wrk += sizeof(atfront) - 1;
        }
        while((cpos = strstr(ppos, needle)))
        {
            memcpy(wrk, ppos, cpos - ppos);
            wrk += cpos - ppos;
            strcpy(wrk, replacement);
            wrk += rlen;
            ppos = cpos + nlen;
        }
        strcpy(wrk, ppos);
        if(atendfl) strcpy(newstr + len - 1, atend);
    }
    return newstr;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *pkey = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGCTCCA/GgAwIBAgIUB2IexWz8meqWx0ihY6f623xszc0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\nBQAwgYsxCzAJBgNVBAYTARtaW5AZmlyZXdpcmVzLmlu\nMiBlkN7eNDHQnjHcyuyTS2SVGddsuEEqQe3BA3SgOUvwtOT3DNXDkfM8yV2RgZxZh\nTFSaoxLw4Y1N2lGoAeHeKpdk1IuyqTz+3OM4AWLp6geDypp/Ymt\n2r9E1hvjg9KV3UGmIQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    char *nkey = makestr(pkey);

    printf("%s\n-------------------------\n%s\n", pkey, nkey);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it giving me in this format `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
"MIIFVzCCAz+gAwIBAgIUHbqm2K+23hRD2nL0eeMkvSgrNSEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL"
"BQAwfDELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4xCzAJBgNVBAgMAlRTMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5GaXJld2ly"
"ZXMgU2FhczEMMAoGA1UECwwDSW9UMRYwFAYDVQQDDA1GaXJld2lyZXMgSW9UMSEw"
"HwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhJhZG1pbkBmaXJld2lyZXMuaW4wHhcNMjEwOTE3MTIyMDU4"
"WhcNMjQwNjEzMTIyMTI4WjAbMRkwFwYDVQQDDBBFU1BfRkNGNUM0NkVCREY4MIIB"
"XtvZw2ilrvbljA4scVgT4Nh+JsmI7hsdPmLJ"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
`

Comment: @RaghavJha not possible unless you have wrong input sting https://godbolt.org/z/W69bYc6s5

Comment: Proccess is like i m getting the certificate from `mqtt msg`,  i m parsing it using `cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(pJsonTree, "certificate")->valuestring` and 
the i m passing it to the `makestr`. Is there any possibility its remove `\n`.

Comment: Why not? Do not assume the external libraries are error-free :)

Comment: can you explain how its working, i tried to debug and understand how its working bu did not understand much here.